# bash with cut to get a value with carriage return \r

Tags: bash

Consider the following bash script

```
NP=`grep nprocshared $GF | cut -d '=' -f2`
echo $NP
if [ $N -ne $NP ]; then
  echo "Error"
```

Please note the `$N` is an integer and it is fine! The file contains

```
%nprocshared=6
%mem=12GB
...
```

With the `set -x` option, I see this in the output

```
++ grep nprocshared file.gjf
++ cut -d = -f2
+ NP=$'6\r'
+ echo $'6\r' 
 6
+ '[' 4 -ne $'6\r' ']'
```

So, I expect `4ne6`, but I don't see that. What it reads the `6` as `6\r`?

Comment: It seems the file was create on MSWin which uses `\r\n` instead of `\n` as line end. Use `dos2unix` or `fromdos` to convert the input file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NP=`grep nprocshared $GF | cut -d '=' -f2 | tr -d \\r`
echo $NP
if [ $N -ne $NP ]; then
  echo "Error"
```

Voilà.

Or, even better, since `NP` is always a number:

```
NP=`grep nprocshared $GF | tr -dc 0-9`
echo $NP
if [ $N -ne $NP ]; then
  echo "Error"
```

Comment: No, still get the same output

Comment: @mahmood, try the new version.